# Convert Java serialization data into a readable file ? linux

Tags: java, linux, serialization, feature-extraction, mallet

I am learning mallet and I am trying out the example. So, I ran this command

bin/mallet import-dir --input sample-data/web/* --output web.mallet

from the link http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/import.php

The output I got is a file named web.mallet but it is not in readable format. It is web.mallet: java serialization data, version 5 . How to convert into a feature vector which can readable or into a csv file or text file.

Comment: for future reference: https://superuser.com/questions/1107042/inspect-serialized-file-content

Answer (score 1):

Mallet provides --print-output TRUE this as an option through which you can print your output to the terminal.

Thanks. :)